# Custom status detector

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

It doesnt detect if theres an emoji or a text before the required activity, help?

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    channel = bot.get_channel(928140305717399662)

    if after.bot == True:
        return

    if before.activities == after.activities:
        return
    
    required_activity = ".gg/hi"
    userHasActivity = False
    for activity in after.activities:
        if isinstance(activity, discord.CustomActivity):
            if str(activity) == required_activity:
                userHasActivity = True
    if userHasActivity:
        emb = discord.Embed()
        emb.description = "thanks for the vanity"
        emb.color = 0xffffff
        await channel.send(f"<@{after.id}>", embed=emb)
    else:
        return
```

Comment: Please include full trace back and exactly what the error is. Please read the new user guide, asking a question is a privilege not a right.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `==` in the `if str(activity) == required_activity:` line with `in`? If I'm not mistaken, you can't get the status separate from the emoji (do correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: i already fixed this by replacing if str(activity).startswith(required_activity) but it keeps spamming over and over again is it the codes problem or is it something else (there is no error shown)